# Macro Button only work on the second click

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

So I created a pivot table and buttons for it. Each button represents a field that will go into the value part of the pivot table. 
Each of those fields is the years 2016, 2017, 2018, and 2019. I also created a button to represent all the years at once too. 
I also apply slicer for the other fields and filters. 
-for the filter, I would just copy the pivot table and put the selected field in the filter tab of the pivot table. (Hope that makes sense)

I want to know why is it that when I first launch the excel. None of the buttons works. It only works if I click on the "All Year" button the second time, meaning the first time it says that object not found. But the second time I clicked it, it would work like normal. All the other buttons would work too.

This problem occurs once I added in the filter for the slicers.

```
Sub Add_Value_MasterCode()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim SField As String

'Set Variable
 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
 SField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text


'Remove Existing Fields
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
End If
Next pf

'Add fields that button was clicked for
pt.PivotFields(SField).Orientation = xlDataField

'Set title and color for each fields
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = SField & " Revenue"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of " & SField).Caption = "Year " & SField
If SField = "2016" Then
    Call year2016
ElseIf SField = "2017" Then
    Call year2017
ElseIf SField = "2018" Then
    Call year2018
ElseIf SField = "2019" Then
    Call year2019
End If

End Sub
```

This is the other code.

```
Sub Add_All()


Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim SField As String

'Set Variable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
SField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

'Remove Existing Fields
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
End If
Next pf

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable1")
            .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2016"), "Year 2016", xlSum
            .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2017"), "Year 2017", xlSum
            .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2018"), "Year 2018", xlSum
            .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2019"), "Year 2019", xlSum
End With


ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "All Years Revenue"

End Sub
```

It seems like it not reading the code

```
 For Each pf In pt.DataFields
 If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
   pf.Orientation = xlHidden
 End If
 Next pf
```

Until I clicked on "All Year" for the second time.

Comment: All the "calls", they just change the color of the graph btw

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? for all buttons. Also, you said it works on the second click of "All Year". If you click a specific year button twice in a row, does it also work on the second click?

Comment: Ok, so I would have click on "All Year" first. Even if the first click there an error. But after that click, ALL of the buttons works. Just figured that out

Comment: So the lines starting with "For Each pf In pt.DataFields
 If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
   pf.Orientation = xlHidden
 End If
 Next pf" It would skip this whole code really since nothing would happen. But it would say the error would be "ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of " & SField).Caption = "Year " & SField"